# Concatenate the strings using list

Tags: python, string, list

Write a function to concatenate a list of strings into a single string. For example:
Input: `(["this ", "is ", "a ", "string"])` == Output: `"this is a string"`

This is the code I have so far but it always returns with the ", " in the result which I have no idea how to get rid of it.

```
def concat(strings):

    list1 = []

    i = 0

    while i < len(strings):

        list1 += [strings[i]]
        i+=1

    return (list1)
```

Comment: `return ' '.join(strings)`?

Comment: "always returns with the `", "`" - That isn't just a minor issue, it's the entire assignment. There is no change between your input and output. Please read your textbook.

Answer (score -1):

Python has a function for this - its called join. It is used on the delimiter you want, an you give the list of strings as the argument.

```
" ".join(strings)  # join strings with " " as delimiter
```

If you want just concatenation, you can use the empty string as delimiter - "".

Comment: the problem is I am not allowed to use the build in function joint.